# Angular 2 Passing Values across components

Tags: angular

I have app.component.ts which is parent and two routes login and register

In my register view, after registration is confirmed i want to pass login view for autologin.

**register.component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
 let params = {
      mobile:this.registrationForm.value.mobile,
      password:this.registrationForm.value.password
    }
    this.sharedService.emitChange({origin:"login", credentials:params });
  }
```

**login.component.ts (My subscribe is not working)**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private sharedService: SharedService) { 
    sharedService.changeEmitted$.subscribe( // not working
      text => {
        console.log(text);
        if (text.origin == 'login') this.login(text.credentials);
      });
  }
```

**app.component.ts (This is working)**

```
sharedService.changeEmitted$.subscribe(
        text => {
          if (text.origin == 'login'){};
        });
```

Hope I was clear. I got two views, login and register and how to communicate between those two ts files. Am i doing it right?

Comment: `SharedService` is provided only once? Only in a single `NgModule`?

Comment: I apologise. I couldnt understand.

Comment: In any `NgModule` you have to provide your `SharedService`. This should only happen once!

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the problem is, that the `SharedService` emits the changes, before the `LoginComponent` is created. Thats why it works inside the `AppComponent`, but not in the `LoginCOmponent`.
A possible solution is to use [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md).
The `ReplaySubject` allows you to define a chche count `n`. It will then save the last `n` emits and notify new `Subscription`s about all of them.
So in your case you should use a `new ReplaySubject<>(1)`.
Everyone who subscribes to this `ReplaySubject` will now get the last emitted value.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot comment I will write this as an answer.*

You are emitting your text before the creation of `LoginComponent`. The `LoginComponent` should be there listening on the event, before the text is emitted.

One solution to this, is to use `localStorage`:

**register.component.ts:**

```
params = {
    mobile:'mobile',
    password:'password'
 }
 onSubmit(): void {
    console.log("putting in localStorage")
    localStorage.setItem('params', JSON.stringify(this.params))
}
```

**login.component.ts**:

```
params:any
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("getting from localStorage")
    this.params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('params'))
    console.log(this.params)
}
```

hope this helps!